# Is there a way to show all defined classNames in the Chrome developer tools?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

I have a REACT Javascript app that dynamically defines a ton of styles using a mix of CSS, SCCS and "useStyles()". Is there a simple way I can see exactly which classNames have been defined in the Chrome developer tools?

Failing that, is there a way I can find and iterate through all the classes in my own code so that I might dump out all the class names to the console?

Comment: what's wrong with just inspecting the DOM and seeing the classes that exist?

Comment: By definded you mean classNames that are in use somewhere in the script? or just a list of all existing classNames in the project?

Comment: The core problem we're trying to solve is that an app we wrote has grown to include many components from different authors, and some of them have overlapping classNames with conflicting attributes. Depending on the path we take through the app, we end up getting quite different styles for a given className as a result, and to help reconcile the differences we're wanting a way to inspect all the classNames at various points through the application so we can pinpoint what's changing and where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do this through Chome Dev Tools unfortunately.

> is there a way I can find and iterate through all the classes in my own code so that I might dump out all the class names to the console?

Something like this (or a variation that formats the data in a way that works for you) should give you all the class names:

```
function getAllClasses() {
    // get all the tags
    const allTagsArray = [...document.getElementsByTagName("*")];

    // get a flattened list of each tag's classList
    const allClasses = allTagsArray.map(tag => [...tag.classList]).flat();

    // get a Set of those classes to remove duplicates
    const uniqueClasses = new Set(allClasses);

    // sort alphabetically and join all the classes by newline for display/readability
    const allUniqueClassesJoinedByNewline = [...uniqueClasses].sort().join('\n');

    console.log(allUniqueClassesJoinedByNewline);
}

getAllClasses()
```

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: After a little refactoring of your answer; you can copy this line of code and execute it in Dev Tool's Console: `[...new Set([...document.getElementsByTagName("*")].map(tag => [...tag.classList]).flat())].sort().join('\n')`